# Typescripts, Jasmine -SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

Im writing a test in typescript but im getting a error. The code is :

```
describe('GET /', () => {
    const data: any = {};
    beforeAll((done) => {
      request.get('http://localhost:200/', (error, response, body) => {
        data.status = response.statusCode;
        data.body = body;
        done();
```

afrter running `npm run test` i get the following error:
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni04M.png)

I tried to run removing `any` form `const data: any = {};` then it gives another error saying "Property 'status' does not exist on type '{}'." how can i solve this problem entirely ?

Comment: You are trying to test your TypeScript as if it were JavaScript, you need to compile it first.

Comment: what if i want to run the test from ts file not from the js file?

Comment: @SädnänMøhøsïn use ts-node

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solutions for this . Insteed of declaring `const data: any = {};` i tried this

```
const data = {
      status: 200,
      body: 'Image',
    };
```

providing values for status and body removed all errors in Typescripts.